# Get class containing string and number from multiple classes

Tags: jquery, regex, match

I have the image below with multiple classes. On click, I need to get the string "wp-image-1228" (those four numbers will always be different) from all of the classes.

I've got the click down, but I can't seem to get what I need using .match.

```
<img class="size-post_gal wp-image-1228 aligncenter">
```

Comment: could you clarify what you need? Do you already have the `.click()` on the `<img>`, and all you need is that number that follows `wp-image-` (which is already granted to be present)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are in the jQuery `.click()` handler and need that ID that follows `wp-image-`:

```
var id = $(this).prop('class').match(/wp-image-([0-9]+)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("img[class^='wp-image-']")` is a valid selector.  that what you're looking for?

Also, here's a working fiddle to get the actual string: http://jsfiddle.net/pFVyE/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').filter(function() {
        var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");                                
        for(i = 0; i < classes.length; i++){
            if(classes[i].match(/^wp-image-/)){
            alert(classes[i]); 
            }
        }    

    }); 
});
```

Comment: I don't want to select it, I'm going to select something else with an id that will match "wp-image-1228" or whatever "wp-image-####"